# Cython program is slower than plain Python (10M options 3.5s vs 3.25s Black Scholes) - what am I missing?

Tags: python, numpy, cython

Okay here's my first Cython program below, the code to price European options on futures (Black Scholes without a dividend).  It runs in 3.5s on 10M options, versus the code I posted below with straight numpy Python 3.25s.  Can anyone point out why my Cython code is slower - like because I used a loop instead of vectorizing the call (not sure in C how to do that, the generated cython code appears to vectorize it though).  Can I use `nogil` and `openmp` around this loop, even though the variables are passed in from numpy arrays?  The simple examples posted on Cython's examples don't compile correctly with `cython.parallel` `prange` on the loop http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/parallelism.html#module-cython.parallel.  Feedback greatly appreciated, apologies for a somewhat open-ended question - others can use this code freely here as a starting point since it already works faster than other work profiled online that I've seen, in C and Python.  Here it is:

Save as `CyBlack.pyx` file to compile (note all inputs are `float64` except `Black_callput` which is `int64`, 1 for a call, -1 for a put).  After compiling, `from CyBlack.CyBlack import CyBlack`:

```
from numpy cimport ndarray
cimport numpy as np
cimport cython

cdef extern from "math.h":
    double exp(double)
    double sqrt(double)
    double log(double)
    double erf(double)

cdef double std_norm_cdf(double x):
    return 0.5*(1+erf(x/sqrt(2.0)))

@cython.boundscheck(False)
cpdef CyBlack(ndarray[np.float64_t, ndim=1] BlackPnL, ndarray[np.float64_t, ndim=1] Black_S, ndarray[np.float64_t, ndim=1] Black_Texpiry, ndarray[np.float64_t, ndim=1] Black_strike, ndarray [np.float64_t, ndim=1] Black_volatility, ndarray[np.float64_t, ndim=1] Black_IR, ndarray[np.int64_t, ndim=1] Black_callput):

    cdef Py_ssize_t i
    cdef Py_ssize_t N = BlackPnL.shape[0]
    cdef double d1, d2


    for i in range(N):
        d1 = ((log(Black_S[i] / Black_strike[i]) + Black_Texpiry[i] * Black_volatility[i] **2 / 2)) / (Black_volatility[i] * sqrt(Black_Texpiry[i]))
        d2 = d1 - Black_volatility[i] * sqrt(Black_Texpiry[i])
        BlackPnL[i] = exp(-Black_IR[i] * Black_Texpiry[i]) * (Black_callput[i] * Black_S[i] * std_norm_cdf(Black_callput[i] * d1) - Black_callput[i] * Black_strike[i] * std_norm_cdf(Black_callput[i] * d2)) 

    return BlackPnL
```

Here is the `setup.py` so others can build this typing: `python setup.py build_ext --inplace` built with VS2015 for Python 3.5 64bit Windows.

```
from setuptools import setup
from setuptools import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext
import numpy as np

ext_modules = [Extension("CyBlack",sources=["CyBlack.pyx"],
          extra_compile_args=['/Ox', '/openmp', '/favor:INTEL64'],
          language='c++')]

setup(
    name= 'Generic model class',
    cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext},
    include_dirs = [np.get_include()],
    ext_modules = ext_modules)
```

Okay and here is my very fast numpy Python only code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import norm

d1=((np.log(Black_S / Black_strike) + Black_Texpiry * Black_volatility **2 / 2)) / (Black_volatility * np.sqrt(Black_Texpiry))
d2=d1 - Black_volatility * np.sqrt(Black_Texpiry)
BlackPnL = np.exp(-Black_IR * Black_Texpiry) * (Black_callput * Black_S * norm.cdf(Black_callput * d1) - Black_callput * Black_strike * norm.cdf(Black_callput * d2))
```

Comment: You shouldn't usually expect Cython to provide a major speedup over vectorized numpy operations.  The numpy operations are already being done in C.

Comment: BrenBarn is right -- it's the *non-vectorized* operations you get the most benefit from dropping to C.  One thing you *can* do, though, to see if there are optimizations not yet captured is to run cython with `-a` and look at the resulting HTML in a browser.  A quick skim makes it look like it's calling `pow` instead of squaring, for example.

Comment: Makes sense, I did change `pow` to `**` and `sqrt` to `**0.5` already, I was thinking I could do something with `no gil` and `openmp` potentially to get multi threading at least.  This is just the most basic finance example which is a good building block for all other analytical option pricing libraries so I think others will benefit from reading this post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I added the following lines before your functions in your cython code and I got a faster result from Cython than Python 2.7

```
@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
@cython.cdivision(True)
```

My results for 10M points

```
%timeit PyBlack(BlackPnL, Black_S, Black_Texpiry, Black_strike, Black_volatility, Black_IR, Black_callput)
1 loops, best of 3: 3.49 s per loop
```

and

```
%timeit CyBlack(BlackPnL, Black_S, Black_Texpiry, Black_strike, Black_volatility, Black_IR, Black_callput)
1 loops, best of 3: 2.12 s per loop
```

EDIT

**CyBlack.pyx**

```
from numpy cimport ndarray
cimport numpy as np
cimport cython

cdef extern from "math.h":
    double exp(double)
    double sqrt(double)
    double log(double)
    double fabs(double)

cdef double a1 = 0.254829592
cdef double a2 = -0.284496736
cdef double a3 =  1.421413741
cdef double a4 = -1.453152027
cdef double a5 =  1.061405429
cdef double p =  0.3275911 

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
@cython.cdivision(True)
cdef inline double erf(double x):
    cdef int sign = 1
    if (x < 0):
        sign = -1
    x = fabs(x)

    cdef double t = 1.0/(1.0 + p*x)
    cdef double y = 1.0 - (((((a5*t + a4)*t) + a3)*t + a2)*t + a1)*t*exp(-x*x)

    return sign*y

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
@cython.cdivision(True)
cdef double std_norm_cdf(double x):
    return 0.5*(1+erf(x/sqrt(2.0)))

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
@cython.cdivision(True)
cpdef CyBlack(ndarray[np.float64_t, ndim=1] BlackPnL, ndarray[np.float64_t, ndim=1] Black_S, ndarray[np.float64_t, ndim=1] Black_Texpiry, ndarray[np.float64_t, ndim=1] Black_strike, ndarray [np.float64_t, ndim=1] Black_volatility, ndarray[np.float64_t, ndim=1] Black_IR, ndarray[np.int64_t, ndim=1] Black_callput):

    cdef Py_ssize_t i
    cdef Py_ssize_t N = BlackPnL.shape[0]
    cdef double d1, d2


    for i in range(N):
        d1 = ((log(Black_S[i] / Black_strike[i]) + Black_Texpiry[i] * Black_volatility[i] **2 / 2)) / (Black_volatility[i] * sqrt(Black_Texpiry[i]))
        d2 = d1 - Black_volatility[i] * sqrt(Black_Texpiry[i])
        BlackPnL[i] = exp(-Black_IR[i] * Black_Texpiry[i]) * (Black_callput[i] * Black_S[i] * std_norm_cdf(Black_callput[i] * d1) - Black_callput[i] * Black_strike[i] * std_norm_cdf(Black_callput[i] * d2)) 

    return BlackPnL
```

**setup.py**

```
try:
    from setuptools import setup
    from setuptools import Extension
except ImportError:
    from distutils.core import setup
    from distutils.extension import Extension

from Cython.Distutils import build_ext
import numpy as np

ext_modules = [Extension("CyBlack",["CyBlack.pyx"])]

setup(
    name= 'Generic model class',
    cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext},
    include_dirs = [np.get_include()],
    ext_modules = ext_modules)
```

Comment: I had tried that earlier and for some reason on python 3.5 it doesn't improve the performance at all.  I have no idea why...

Comment: Did you change the compiler options by chance?

Comment: I added the code I used in my answer. I didn't use your ```extra_compile_args = ['/EHsc', '/openmp', '/favor:INTEL64']``` and I had to write my own ```erf``` function.

Comment: I edited my setup.py in the original post to be compatible with Python 3.5 and used your template as the starting point.  So far with the options I posted down to 3.25s roughly using your erf function, tied with Python 3.5 native numpy libraries.

Comment: I upvoted your answer, thanks for actually trying the code out.  For some reason with Python 3.5 it makes little difference.  I've posted another question where I have actually added OpenMP but can't seem to call it after compiling here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37198246/cython-parallel-implementation-openmp-of-black-scholes-with-numpy-integrated-can

Comment: Just selected your answer - I recompiled it and am seeing a great improvement: %timeit CyBlack(BlackPnL, Black_S, Black_Texpiry, Black_strike, Black_volatility, Black_IR, Black_callput)
1 loop, best of 3: 2.05 s per loop

Comment: Just FYI there is a bug in the erf calculation above. I saw a very similar approximation online though, not sure what is not okay there. Just posting this as a note to those wanting to implement their own algo to check their results to ensure they are correct (using the C erf function I get exactly the same results out of my python function). BUT I just confirmed changing the `cdef double std_norm_cdf(double x)` to `cdef inline double std_norm_cdf(double x):` drops it down to 2.74s.

Comment: This approximation I mentioned is much better, at most $0.015 difference on 10M options (2.2s):                                                                                                                                       `cdef inline double std_norm_cdf(double x):
      cdef double a = -0.07056
      cdef double b = -1.5976
      return (1/(1 + exp(a * (x*x*x) +b * x)))`

Comment: The approximation posted in this answer from @sebacastroh is from here, but I don't suggest using it due to the huge difference between that and the actual ERF C function.  The simpler approximation above is better.  However, here is the link for reference http://www.johndcook.com/blog/cpp_erf/